# Measure to show the data as "daily","weekly","monthly" in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have data of few years of submitted and unsubmitted application, which I am showing in an area chart. I want to add filters like "daily"(it should show today's submitted & unsubmitted), "weekly"
( it should show the current week data), "monthly" (it should show the current month data )
My data format:
[image: Data Format]

Please help me with those three measures, which I can use as a filter. I have already done the Dynamically Add or Remove Measures to a slicer.
Following I want to achieve, Internally those three options "daily", "weekly" and "monthly" I have linked with three dummy Measures. Or else you can suggest any other approach. 
[image: requirement]

Currently, I got a suggestion from powerbi community,
to use to measure for the submitted & unsubmitted, which DAX formular & link I am sharing below, Now the graph is changing as per the option clicked but the values it is sowing is wrong.
Measure :

```
Submitted Sum =

var Daily_Sum= CALCULATE(SUM(Applicant_data[Submitted]),ALLEXCEPT(Applicant_data, Applicant_data[Postion Type ],Applicant_data[Date]))

var Weekly_Sum=CALCULATE(SUM(Applicant_data[Submitted]),FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Applicant_data), YEAR(Applicant_data[Date]) =YEAR(MAX(Applicant_data[Date]))&&WEEKNUM(Applicant_data[Date]) =WEEKNUM(MAX(Applicant_data[Date]))))

Var Monthly_Sum= CALCULATE(SUM(Applicant_data[Submitted]),FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Applicant_data), YEAR(Applicant_data[Date]) =YEAR(MAX(Applicant_data[Date]))&&MONTH(Applicant_data[Date]) =MONTH(MAX(Applicant_data[Date]))))

return

IF(ISFILTERED('_Measure'[Selection]),
SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE('_Measure'[Selection]),
"Daily", Daily_Sum,
"Weekly", Weekly_Sum,
"Monthly", Monthly_Sum
),
BLANK()
)
```

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Measure-to-show-the-data-as-daily-weekly-monthly-in-power-bi/m-p/1039068#M488207

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 common ways to make this work :

### Way-1 : Utilizing Power Query

1. Create a "Date Table" using the date column in power query
2. Add 3 calculated columns that extracts month, week and day info from the "Date" column in the newly created "Date Table".
3. Now, unpivot the "month", "day" and "year" columns and load the file.
4. Create a one to many relationship with "Date" columns as common in both tables and there you go.

### Way-2 (Using Drill-through buttons).

Use the recent feature update of Power BI, i.e., drilling the data using buttons. So, you just need to create a date hierarchy and then drill through using buttons for "month", "week"and "day".

I hope this will help you.

If you still got the doubt then please send me the dataset and I will give you an detailed explanation on this.

Comment: let me know your mail id , so that I can share the dataset.

Comment: mail me at -: quantumudit@gmail.com and please do let me know here, once you mailed the dataset.

Comment: Please check your mail.

Comment: I have sent you thr pbix file with solution. Please check that out